# jQuery element add event doesn't response to certain syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery problem, jQuery doesn't response to certain syntax:

```
$("#itemid").change(function(e){....});
```

it didn't work at all. but when I use this :

```
$(document).on("change", "#itemid", function(e){....});
```

it works well.
I have read jQuery manual and didn't find any answers.
My testing browser is Chrome Version 36.

Comment: What type of element is `#itemid`? Is it added dynamically?

Comment: is #itemid a select element?

Comment: it is  <input type='file' />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that is because events are attached before DOM is rendered on page.

-You need to wrap the events in document ready if elements are not added dynamically:

```
$(document).ready(function(){// or $(function(){
 $("#itemid").change(function(e){....});
});
```

-If elements are added dynamically then you need to use event delegation:

```
$(document).on("change", "#itemid", function(e){....});
```